# Two Range Data annotations MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, range, data-annotations

I'm trying use data annotations to validate a DropDown list in MVC. The values for the dropdown list range from 10-23 and then it can also be 99. Is there a way to use two range data annotations to only allow those possible values through?

something like

```
[Range(10-23)]
[Range(99-99)]
public int DropDownListValue { get; set; }
```

or is there a regular expression or something that can do this for me? Or would I just be better off making a custom validator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression attribute to achieve this

```
[RegularExpression("^(1[0-9]|2[0-3]|99)$")]
public int DropDownListValue { get; set; }
```

**Notes:**

1. **`1[0-9]`** validates between 10 and 19
2. **`2[0-3]`** validates between 20 and 23
3. **`99`** validates to be 99 :)
4. You can add more validation with a `|` between them
5. `^` and `$` make sure that the entire string is validated (*incorrect*: a11a, a11, 11a) (*correct*: 11).

Comment: Perfect, I'm not used to using regular expressions so I wasn't sure how to go about that. Can you just remind me what the ^ and $ mean? ^ is starts with and $ is ends with correct?

Comment: @ryanmiller You are correct :). I highlighted why is this necesary in my answer.